# add spacing top of page when use get_header in wordpress

Tags: php, css, wordpress, space

add space top of page when use this code :

```
<?php get_header(); ?>
```

but In normal , Code is correct and not space top of page

pic after add get_header :

[image]

Comment: Use CSS to achieve this?

Comment: Add this to your body css `{ margin: 50px 0 0 0; }`

Comment: i add margin:50px 0 0 0; but 50px sum to height :(

Comment: Are you editing an existing template? Without seeing a live example, there is no way of knowing whats wrong, and its hard to understand your problem. Are you saying the space that appears at the top is an error, or you want a space but dont get one?

Comment: yes i am editing this template , inspect element add to my question , chek it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand your issue.. give this a try:

```
* {
    margin:0; padding:0;
}
body {
    padding-top: 50px;
}
```

Then adjust to your needs.

Answer (score 0):

If you just added space or new line characters then HTML will just remove them.

You have to add some tags like `<br>` or use CSS to added the space required.